# C++ Armadillo reshape a matrix with only one dimension size

Tags: c++, armadillo

Using [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html), how do I reshape a matrix when I only specify one dimension size?

In [Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), there is this example of such functionality:

> Reshape a 6-by-6 magic square matrix into a matrix that has only 3
>   columns. Specify [] for the first dimension size to let reshape
>   automatically calculate the appropriate number of rows.
>
> ```
> A = magic(6);
> B = reshape(A,[],3);
> ```
>
> The result is a 12-by-3 matrix, which maintains the same number of
>   elements (36) as the original 6-by-6 matrix. The elements in B also
>   maintain their columnwise order from A.

How can that be accomplished with Armadillo?

Comment: I think I'll just have to do a calculation using the size/shape of the first matrix and the known size of the dimension in the second matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.size()` to get the total number of elements of your matrix and calculate the dimensions yourself.
Example:

```
B = reshape(A, A.size()/3, 3);
```